Swift: stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'
I am building an App Intent that has an AppEntity parameter that can depend on another parameter. I have found that IntentParameterDependency is exactly the tool for the job ... but it's iOS17 only, and I need to support iOS16 as well.
The IntentParameterDependency is defined inside a EntityQuery like this:
@IntentParameterDependency<CJAddLog>(
            \.$contactName
        )
        var intent

But just adding @available(iOS 17.0, *) on top of this results in a compiler error:

Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with
'@available'

What's the correct way to handle this? None of the existing answers to related questions seem to address this.

What do you want to do in iOS 16 then?

Mark whole class/struct that have that property with @available(iOS 17.0, *)

In iOS16, I can just query the whole list, without filtering by the 'contactName' dependancy. If I mark the whole class/struct as only available to iOS17, then the AppIntent will then show availability errors for the AppEntity I want to work with

It's your war how to resolve availability errors in that case. For example you can have two entities conforming AppEntity: one for iOS 16 and another for 17+

Then the problem gets shifted up to the AppIntent. How do you create an AppIntent while switching between a @Parameter of type CustomAppEntity, one that works for  iOS16 and one that works for iOS17?
